# It is possible to clone a user in salesforce from exsting user?

Tags: user

I want to create same clone user from existing user  in salesforce.

Answer (score 8):

It is possible. Please take a look at below link

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000grMNAAY

I did try this on my end by creating a custom link on User Object & it worked smooth
[image]

**Goto Setup-> Customise->Users-> Custom Links -> New Button or Link**[image]